# Debug JavaScript errors on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, debugging

Is there any way to debug a JavaScript page runing on iPad?

Comment: For an iPhone, click the settings icon on the home screen and edit safari settings. Developer mode. Can't confirm it's the same for iPad. Probably is though.

Comment: It's the same on iPad (at least, on the iOS simulator under Xcode). But if there's an error it can help you, if there's no error but still some kind of layout issue *because it's an iPad* then you are still stuck ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to this location, and enable debug console.

### iOS6:

Debug Console is gone. Use an alternative to get it to work. Such as Firebug Lite. Look at the related question here: [iOS6 - removed console log for IPad - how to use web inspector on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12583275/438970)

### iOS5:

```
Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Debug Console
```

### Older:

```
Settings -> Safari -> Developer -> Debug Console
```

Comment: maybe developer is? Guess they renamed it

Comment: Good! I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get up and running fast. 
Just go sign up and add the tracking html codes from http://trackjs.com
The javascript errors shows up immediately then when I used on my iPad2.

And then you can just remove the tracking code later too if you decide not to track anymore errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this iPad app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idebug/id525956537?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

this app loads firebug lite on your web page so you can debug javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe firebug lite is something for you http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite 
It is a bookmarklet.

Comment: on iOS? Nah, it doesn't work there. You can't bookmark a javascript: link; there's no drag and drop support so you can't drag the link.

Comment: you can totally bookmark a javascript link on iOS.  Lots of scriptlets out there.

Comment: Firebug lite is no longer available (via that link).