# iPad JavaScript Error not helpful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I get the following error and iPad but not in desktop browsers:

```
JavaScript: Error
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

This is a larger js application, and this error message is totally unhelpful. Is there any way I can get the line number of the error or anymore information?

Update: This just got funky.

```
line : 0    
page : undefined
desc : TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
chr  : undefined
```

Did the user agent spoofing in FF and safari. No error.

Comment: I had the same issue, and while the window.onerror suggestion was a start, I got the same unhelpful results. I ended up having to litter my scripts with console.logs to narrow in. With  iOS it feels like we've backtracked to ie6 days with error debugging...

My specific issue was that I was assuming function(){}.bind() was supported in my app. It wasn't, but my dev browsers (Safari/Chrome) do support it natively, while iOS Safari apparently does not.

Comment: Believe it or not, `.bind` was my issue too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try registering a custom error handler to `window.onerror`

```
window.onerror = function (desc,page,line,chr)
{ alert('Line:'+line); }
```

`desc` = Error message
`page` = File/Page where the error occured
`line` = Well...
`chr` = Character position of the error in the line

Comment: try the `page` variable :) - i've edited the answer to include the content information for all four variables :)

Comment: for page I get 'undefined', weird

Comment: That can happen if the code is loaded via ajax or eval'd into place. You only got a closure or some objects floating in the javascript machine without any existing code in any file. The Javascript code just existed inside a variable at runtime. - This can also happen if the code is compressed by dean.edwards /packer/ for example. Try to use unpacked/unminified versions of all files if available.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error inside, let's say safari when you switch the UserAgent for the browser to iPad? Maybe it's a glitch in some browser specific code. Once you got it to throw errors in safari you could insert breakpoints and see the "undefined" code sequences in the code view.

Comment: Yeah once you're in twilight you also might want to try FirebugLITE - http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite - That's runnable on the iPad too :)

Comment: I tried that actually. Error occurs before firebug will open.

Comment: Use firebug in a html document framing the errornous page on the same host/domain. You should be able to see everything happening in the iframe too as there is no crossdomain block. - Using that you can load the errornous page with a x second delay.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10198/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-bardiir)

Answer (score 2):

If you bind an error handler to window.onerror, it should give you the line number, e.g.

```
window.onerror = function(msg,url,line) {
   alert('The error is on line '+line);
}
```

This question: [Debug JavaScript errors on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834407/debug-javascript-errors-on-ipad) seems to indicate you can enable debugging too.

If the script is loaded dynamically, though, it can be hard to get such info in any environment.