# Express JS pass console log to view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to pass the console.log function to my view in Node Express, I've tried:

```
res.render('index', {
"title" : 'My page',
"logger": console.log
}
```

I've also tried this

```
res.render('index', {
"title" : 'My page',
"logger": function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}
```

But it always comes through as empty, am I missing something?

**fwiw** this is how I'm trying to output it in my view

```
script
    log = #{logger};
```

### For those that want to know the why

I develop on my iPad 2 while on the move (it's jailbroken) and Apple in their wisdom remove the develop toolbar in recent versions so I'm stuck with alerts which are just awful so I want a makeshift console.log to my terminal instead.

[EDIT]

### If I used Socket I/O

I could subscribe on the backend to a "log" event on the front end and emit these events and data to console log.

I've not put this as an answer because I don't think it's the best way but this would work I think.

Comment: that won't work. both scripts are executed in different contexts (on different devices).

Comment: iOS 6 added a very usable Web Inspector which you can access using Safari on your computer.

Comment: @robertklep Missing the point here.. Didn't you read the OP?

Comment: @Floby there must be a way to do a console log from the front end, I doubt it's a clear cut "Nope, can't be done" case

Comment: @DaveMackintosh not missing the point, just saying that console.log still works, just differently.

Comment: @robertklep The point is, I'm not at a computer when I need to use console.log hence looking for a work-around. I think I'll go with Socket I/O for now.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh or look at the solutions presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583275/ios6-removed-console-log-for-ipad-how-to-use-web-inspector-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could expose the console.log() function in app.locals if you're using Express 3. See the documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals).

So, where you configure your server you might have something like...

```
app.configure(function(){
  // some other configuration code

  app.locals.logger = function(arguments) {
    console.log(arguments);
  }

});
```

Which you could then access in your view like this...

```
script
  var log = #{logger};
  log("Hello, world!");
```

Which in Chrome, for example, logs "Hello, world!" to the web inspector.